# Itemize item size in roboto font

Tags: beamer, fonts

Kindly check that how the circle in itemized item has shrunk to a dot while using `roboto` font. If I don't use roboto, the circle is ideal, and I want to keep that circle size with roboto.

Can I do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage{roboto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Hello
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `itemize items` are based on `\textbullet`. You see the `\textbullet` from `roboto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a bigger circle, scale it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\raisebox{-0.35em}{\scalebox{2}{\textbullet}}}
\usepackage{roboto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Hello
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want the original symbol, change the font family of the itemize item:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\begingroup\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\textbullet\endgroup}
\usepackage{roboto}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Hello
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```